# Fallback img src for images from external sites

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to display images from other sites and have a view model with a `imgsrc` property that references an image URL. Then I have the following HTML binding:

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src : imgsrc }" />
```

The problem is that with a bound image being external, I could get a 404 or 500 response if the external site is having issues; therefore, I want to display a fallback image in case we can't load the image.

How can this be achieved using KnockoutJS?

Comment: My situation is different as I don't have control over whether the image is reachable or not as the image is located externally, in the end onerror as suggested by @gkatai solved the issue

Comment: The question that this one was marked a duplicate of, is asking something completely different - hiding an image based on *another* property. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `onerror` event.

HTML:

```
<img id="pic" data-bind="attr: { src : imgsrc }" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var myViewModel = {
    imgsrc: ko.computed(function () {
        var pic = document.getElementById('pic');
        pic.onerror = function () {
            pic.src = 'fallback image url';
        };
        return 'image url';
    }, this)
};

ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/R4SV7/1/

Comment: using DOM directly from VM is a anti pattern, creating a binding handler is the way togo if you need custom access to the DOM